# Как создать пользователя ftp в vsftpd на ubuntu чтобы он мог работать по обычному FTP а не SFTP?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp, vsftpd

Как создать пользователя ftp в vsftpd на ubuntu чтобы он мог работать по обычному FTP а не SFTP? Сейчас не дает подключиться по 21 порту. И в догонку - как задать ему домашнюю папку и нужные права на запись, удаление и редактирование этой папкой. При этом владелец папки должен оставаться прежним. Пробовал через создание /etc/vsftpd_user_conf/ivanov с внесением в него local_root=/var/www/example1.com - не получается, даже в указанную папку зайти не может

Comment: Простите, а зачем вам устаревший FTP, если есть современный и безопасный SFTP?

Comment: есть определенная задача. Кстати ожидал этот вопрос )